# Elasticsearch: Documents inside a year

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to get whichever document has a date field `dateField` where `year(dateField) = 2016`.

In short, I need to get all the documents which has informed `dateField` on 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to check for a single year, the easiest way is to use a `range` filter in which you check that the `dateField` is between Jan 1st and Dec 31st of year 2016:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "dateField": {
              "gte": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lt": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You have two other solutions:

1. You create a `year` field inside your document at indexing time so you can search on it using a `term` or `range` query/filter
2. You use a `script` filter at search time

The first option is more performant, but in case you want to try the second options, it goes like this:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "doc.dateField.date.getYear() == year",
              "params": {
                 "year": 2016
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```